# Scraping a website for certain content that shows after a button click with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to scrape from an online tour booking site the earliest available date of each product, but the information only shows after the user clicks on the calendar.

The original html code of the calendar:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="datepicker"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="toggle icon-calendar"></div> <input type="text" id="datepicker-input" class="datepicker-input" placeholder="Choose your date" autocomplete="off" readonly="" required=""> </div> <div class="pika-single is-hidden is-bound" style="position: static; left: auto; top: auto;"></div></div>
```

After clicking to open the calendar on the website, below is the html code:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="datepicker"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="toggle icon-calendar"></div> <input type="text" id="datepicker-input" class="datepicker-input" placeholder="Choose your date" autocomplete="off" readonly="" required="" aria-label="Use the arrow keys to pick a date"> </div> <div class="pika-single is-bound is-hidden" style="position: static; left: auto; top: auto;"><div class="pika-lendar"><div id="pika-title-es" class="pika-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive"><div class="pika-label">April<select class="pika-select pika-select-month" tabindex="-1"><option value="0" disabled="disabled">January</option><option value="1" disabled="disabled">February</option><option value="2" disabled="disabled">March</option><option value="3" selected="selected">April</option><option value="4">May</option><option value="5">June</option><option value="6">July</option><option value="7">August</option><option value="8">September</option><option value="9">October</option><option value="10">November</option><option value="11">December</option></select></div><div class="pika-label">2019<span></span><select class="pika-select pika-select-year" tabindex="-1"><option value="2019" selected="selected">2019</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2022">2022</option><option value="2023">2023</option><option value="2024">2024</option><option value="2025">2025</option><option value="2026">2026</option><option value="2027">2027</option><option value="2028">2028</option><option value="2029">2029</option></select></div><button class="pika-prev is-disabled" type="button">Previous Month</button><button class="pika-next" type="button">Next Month</button></div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pika-table" role="grid" aria-labelledby="pika-title-es"><thead><tr><th scope="col"><abbr title="Sunday">Sun</abbr></th><th scope="col"><abbr title="Monday">Mon</abbr></th><th scope="col"><abbr title="Tuesday">Tue</abbr></th><th scope="col"><abbr title="Wednesday">Wed</abbr></th><th scope="col"><abbr title="Thursday">Thu</abbr></th><th scope="col"><abbr title="Friday">Fri</abbr></th><th scope="col"><abbr title="Saturday">Sat</abbr></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="pika-row"><td class="is-empty"></td><td data-day="1" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="1">1</button></td><td data-day="2" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="2">2</button></td><td data-day="3" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="3">3</button></td><td data-day="4" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="4">4</button></td><td data-day="5" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="5">5</button></td><td data-day="6" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="6">6</button></td></tr><tr class="pika-row"><td data-day="7" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="7">7</button></td><td data-day="8" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="8">8</button></td><td data-day="9" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="9">9</button></td><td data-day="10" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="10">10</button></td><td data-day="11" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="11">11</button></td><td data-day="12" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="12">12</button></td><td data-day="13" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="13">13</button></td></tr><tr class="pika-row"><td data-day="14" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="14">14</button></td><td data-day="15" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="15">15</button></td><td data-day="16" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="16">16</button></td><td data-day="17" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="17">17</button></td><td data-day="18" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="18">18</button></td><td data-day="19" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="19">19</button></td><td data-day="20" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="20">20</button></td></tr><tr class="pika-row"><td data-day="21" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="21">21</button></td><td data-day="22" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="22">22</button></td><td data-day="23" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="23">23</button></td><td data-day="24" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="24">24</button></td><td data-day="25" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="25">25</button></td><td data-day="26" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="26">26</button></td><td data-day="27" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="27">27</button></td></tr><tr class="pika-row"><td data-day="28" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="28">28</button></td><td data-day="29" class="is-disabled is-not-available" aria-selected="false"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="29">29</button></td><td data-day="30" class="is-today is-selected is-not-available" aria-selected="true"><button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2019" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="30">30</button></td><td class="is-empty"></td><td class="is-empty"></td><td class="is-empty"></td><td class="is-empty"></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
```

For example, today is 2019-04-30, I want to get the following from the website so I know it's not available today.

```
<td data-day="30" class="is-today is-selected is-not-available"
```

Below is my script for the scraper. Should I use the put method and payload to get the data?

```
function Scraper{
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName(sheetname);

 var params = { 

 headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Accept': "application/json"},

 muteHttpExceptions: true,

 method: "GET",

 contentType: "application/json",

 validateHttpsCertificates: false,

 };

 var url = "XXX" 

 var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params).getContentText()

 var regex ="is-today.*available"

 var regexGI = new RegExp(regex, "gi")    

 var matched = html.match(regexGI)

 if (matched != null){

  matched[0] = matched[0].substring(0,5000);

  sheet.getRange(row,col_output).setValue(matched[0])  
 } 
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your script?

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script can't access the DOM that is being managed by your web browser, so you should check what the button does. If it do a POST request, maybe you could do it from the your script.